# AngularJs ngclick fires before onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete

In my application, there are two elements. one is autocomplete element and another one is button.

My problem is, In desktop chrome - jquery onChange of autocomplete element [#COUNTRY_LIST] fires below button ng-click. but in Android mobile chrome, ng-click fires first and calls onChange. Is there any way to prevent onChange when ng-click fires.

**Auto Complete element and its ID is COUNTRY_LIST**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.ctList" id="COUNTRY_LIST" placeholder="Key in to auto search"/>

$(document).on("change","#COUNTRY_LIST", function (e) {
   var $scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("DATA")).scope();
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // make clear selected country list

        // In desktop chrome - this function calls before COUNTRY_LIST change
        // In Android mobile chrome - this function calls afterCOUNTRY_LIST change

    });
});
```

**Next Button element**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="callNext()">Next</button>

$scope.callNext= function() {
    // In Android mobile chrome - this function calls before COUNTRY_LIST change
    // In desktop chrome - this function calls after COUNTRY_LIST change
}
```

Comment: did you tried to use ng-change directive?

Comment: ng-change calling every time when i type in autocomplete box

Comment: how i can see, you don't use ng-change. maybe this http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/G8S32/ fiddele will be useful

Comment: dorintufar. Thanks. I am using Autocomplete box not select box

Answer (score 0):

Try using Typeahead (ui.bootstrap.typeahead). [Refer Docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead)